# About Google and granular OAuth authorization

Tags: oauth, calendar, gmail

Today I received a notice about the need to handle granular Google Account permissions. In our case, we only use gmail and calendar scopes, and we are doing each authorization process one by one, using one special form for each one.

Doing this way, we are already using a granular way, but I will thank a lot if someone can give me a confirmation.

Best regards.